# Suppose that a function $f$ has a pole of order two at $z_0$ and is holomorphic on $\mathbb C /(z_0)$ let $g(z) = (z-z_0)^2f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that a function $f$ has a pole of order two at $z_0$ and is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_0\}$.

Let $g(z) := (z-z_0)^2f(z)$.

Why is $g(z_0)$ not equal to $0$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask why $f(z_{0})\not=0$?

Comment: no the question is fine

Comment: Then perhaps you've interchanged $f$ and $g$ while typing the question?

Comment: What is your definition of a pole of order 2?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f$ has a Laurent series
$$
f(z) = \frac{{a_{ - 2} }}{{(z - z_0 )^2 }} + \frac{{a_{ - 1} }}{{z - z_0 }} + a_0  + a_1 (z - z_0 ) +  \cdots 
$$
around $z_0$ with $a_{-2}\neq 0$.

Comment: I just would add that this representation of $f$ near $z_0$ (in particular the fact that $a_{-2}\neq0$) follows by the definition of holomorphic function with a pole of order 2 at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the previous answer,

$\displaystyle{f(z)=\frac{a_{-2 }+a_{-1}(z-z_0)+a_0(z-z_0)^2 +a_1(z-z_0)^3+\cdots}{(z-z_0)^2}=\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}}$,

where,

$\displaystyle{g(z)=a_{-2 }+a_{-1}(z-z_0)+a_0(z-z_0)^2 +a_1(z-z_0)^3+\cdots}$

is analytic, with $\displaystyle{g(z_0)=a_{-2}\neq 0}$.